# Replacing letters in lists in Python

Tags: python

Say I have the following variables:

## Standard Alphabet List

original = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"

## Encrypted Alphabet List

encrypted = "NOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklm"

I want to make a for loop to reassign some user input to take the letter and replace it with the corresponding letter.

If I type in AbC I want to output NoP.

The problem is, I don't know python, so I don't know what I would use to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Your code would look something like this:

```
original = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
encrypted ="NOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklm"

#Create a dictionary
mapping = {}

# populate it.
for x,y in zip(original, encrypted):
    mapping[x] = y

#Use the mapping to translate 
input = "AbC"
output = "".join([mapping[x] for x in input])

print output
```